# How does webpack load a react-router/lib/HashHistory or react-router/lib/BrowserHistory?

Tags: webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to get up and running with webpack-dev-server and react-router. My trouble is that I can't seem to get even the basic page loaded- my main file looks like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { history } from 'react-router/lib/HashHistory'
import App from './js/app'


React.render(<App history={history} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

And I have a standart webpack.config.js.

How is webpack loading anything from 'react-router/lib/HashHistory' ? That router does not yield any physical file on the HDD. Where is that loaded from?
Could it be just a problem on the latest beta like this [issue](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1802) suggests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In RR@1.0.0beta4 `History` moved to it's own NPM module https://www.npmjs.com/package/history

```
import createHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';  
React.render(<Router history={createHistory()} routes={routes}/>
             , document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: How come I didn't find this in the docs, because I looked everywhere trying to solve this problem!